# Why do some groups of tourists include someone carrying a banner?

Tags: sightseeing, group-travel

While traveling in Thailand I have seen a lot of groups of Chinese tourists.  But one thing is very confusing to me, every group has someone who was carrying a some sort of banner, and those banners were not unique. What does those banners mean? Why do the tour groups carry them?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I took a tour of NYC, our tour guide carried a light sabre.

Comment: I've seen this happen in Amsterdam and other large cities. Primarily by large, Asian groups but others are picking it up as well.

Comment: Picking it up? I remember traveling with a group of Dutch people in the 1980's where one of the group wore a knitted cap that was long enough to sit on and when people in the group were missing in a crowd he would stretch it upward so all could see it from a distance. And he was not the only one with an easy to recognize item to stick in the air.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's like that everywhere for guided tours (not just Chinese people)

It makes it easier to follow the guide.

The guide tour leader will carry a flag so that if/when people get lost they can spot the flag;

This is especially the case now because most guides have radio systems so that people can be further away from the guide and still hear her/him.

Comment: Sometimes a folded umbrella.

Comment: "This is especially the case now because most guides have radio systems so that people can be further away from the guide and still hear her/him." - while you're right having a flag or an umbrella is quite common everywhere for tour guides, I have to say that I feel this last part is actually very specific to Chinese groups. When in noisy environments (such as tourism hotspots with many simultaneous guided tours), in plenty of places I've taken tours in, the reaction is to stand closer to the guide. I have seen almost only in China that instead, tour guides simply try to be even noisier ...

Comment: ... than all the other groups by using a microphone (which, even without the surrounding noise, often makes the guides' English incomprehensible to me due to static noise and distortion).

Comment: One option I've seen is a telescoping pointer with a sign attached to the tip.

Comment: @AE I remember that from the 1970s.

Comment: Seeing this in Japan a lot. I rarely saw it in Europe with Europeans. I tend to believe it's especially an Asian thing. But that's completely based on my personal experience.

Comment: I've taken a few guided tours in Europe, NYC and Vietnam and in nearly all tours the tour guide will have something distinctive. Although in Europe and NYC I didn't really need something to know who my guide was, in Vietnam I found it harder to tell between groups of Asians being western myself and bad a recognising faces at the best of times... and without my guide with a `teddy bear on a stick` I may have lost him.

Comment: The other version of this I've seen involves giving everyone in the group an identical, brightly-colored T-shirt.  This is more common when there are children in the group, such as a school field trip or a large family.  (This is not as uniquely Asian as the flag thing.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: This can be a separate thing; the umbrella/flag/other tall sign serves for tourists finding and following their guide. The t-shirt (or cap, which I have also seen, even in Asian all-adult groups) is there so the guide can quickly identify and collect everyone belonging to their group. Thus, both can be used in combination and serve different, non-overlapping purposes.

Answer (score 29):

For the same reason that Western and Near Eastern militaries have been carrying "colours, standards (and) guidons" for 7,000 years: so the troops know where the commander is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_colours,_standards_and_guidons

> In military organizations, the practice of carrying colours, standards or guidons, both **to act as a rallying point for troops and to mark the location of the commander**, is thought to have originated in Ancient Egypt some 5,000 years ago.

The ancient Chinese certainly had something similar, because flags are an obvious solution to the problem of letting troops in battle (and tourists in a crowded area) know where the leader is.

Comment: The military aspect is deprecated, however, as the flag also lets the enemy sniper(s) know where the commander is.

Comment: @aroth Now they're just used in parades and PT.

Comment: While there is the humorous notion of tourists "invading".... you think that is their actual intention now? :)

Answer (score 15):

This is very common in China. You might have a number of tour groups simultaneously at a busy tourist site and the use of a flag (and stickers on the participants) helps keep them together and is very much necessary. Sometimes the tour leader will dress in minority costume as well (for example in Lijiang), which also helps them stand out from the crowd.

It's probably not as necessary in Thailand where it is unlikely a whole gaggle of similar groups will converge on one spot, but the participants probably feel more comfortable having the security of seeing the flag and having a travel company sticker.

Photo below (without arrows) from the [SCMP](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/hong-kong-economy/article/3008418/first-day-mini-golden-week-sees-fewer-mainland).

[image]

Imagine maybe dozen tour groups, from many different tour companies, simultaneously at a single crowded site (say on a mountainside with a single spot where scenic photos of one or two people are preferred). Everyone is milling about and/or waiting their turn at the photo spot, buying food or souvenirs from the vendors, and it would be very easy to get separated from your tour group.

Chinese mass-market tours also tend to cram as many items as possible into their itinerary.

Comment: Emphasis: Crowded. Sometimes China can get really crowded, there's lotsa people there.

Comment: @dotancohen Jarjar? My only contact with Jarjar was an [incredibly obnoxious animated singing Star Wars animatronic toy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWF250xW-fQ) a friend bought my son (just to be irritating). If it's a joke, I guess it went over my head.

Answer (score 5):

As others said, you'll see those everywhere, not only in Thailand. Each tour guide has a stick with some special identifying items, most often flag or stuffed animals, to make them visible in a crowded area. It's also useful for tours that tourists join individually and arrive at the meeting point on their own. European tourist companies more commonly use umbrellas, especially on free-walking tours.

I don't know why you said it's not unique but you don't usually see 2 guides with the same flag, even when they both use company flags and come from the same company because in that case they'll choose different ways to hang on the stick

In Vietnam and China you'll also see tourist companies giving each tourist a bright color hat so that the whole group can stay together, and one can find the group easily when they lost their way. It's also good for advertising the company